# How to add more than four icons in windows phone application bar?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I want to add more than 4 total 6 icons in windows phone application bar, but the windows didn't allow to add more than 4 icons in app bar?? Is there any idea to add six icons in app bar, Or I have to create custom menu bar,, If show, can I get link which taught about creation of custom application bar for windows phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add more then 4 app bar icons, because there is no enough space to place them all one next to each other (remember, that WP can be run on 3 different resolutions).

You should use Application Bar Menu Items for some of your actions. They will be visible as text links when user expands the app bar using *(...)*:

[image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC531092.png]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add more than 4 application Bar icons,and so best way is create your own user control with 6 icons and drag it on the bottom of the screen,thats the simple.

Comment: Yes, I found creating own custom menu bar is good, if more than 4 icons needed.